# SOQL Query Trigger loading time

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I am writing a trigger for when a Lead is inserted, I want to query all of our org's Contacts to ensure that the Lead's email does not already exist under a Contact. I am using:

```
List<Contact> allContacts = [select id, email from Contact];
```

My fear is that we have 600,000+ Contacts in the org, is this going to cause alot of loading time or slow down user's systems at all? Are there any preferred methods to the query I used above?

Comment: With a number of contacts that large, I think a trigger might not be the best way to go.  You could do your call asynchronously in a helper class and call that from the trigger.  A better approach might be to use Batch Apex for this.  Its really a matter of whether you truly need it in Real Time or can wait for periodic reports that are hourly, daily, etc.

Comment: Real time would be best. But I am going to try out the trigger method in the full sandbox first to see how it goes, if nothing doing then yeah, thanks, I'll probably go with Batch.

Comment: FYI, you should bear in mind that the consequence of trying to access too much data is not only a slowing down but a dead stop with an uncatchable exception thrown. So you always need to think about the [governor limits](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) e.g. a maximum of 10,000 rows retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check Contacts that may have the same Email of the Lead then add a WHERE clause that searches for Contact Email

```
Map<String, Lead> emailLeadMap = new Map<String, Lead>();
for(Lead l : trigger.new){
    emailLeadMap.put( l.Email, l );
}
List<Contact> contactsWithMatchingEmail = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :emailLeadMap.keySet()];
```

//Processing here.

This will get you all Contacts that match your Lead email.
With the Map you can retrieve your Lead record if necessary to do you processing.

Comment: Thanks, this will work better I'll go with this for now and test. Thanks for editing too as I was getting an "Initial term of field expression must be a concrete blah blah blah"

Answer (score 0):

If anybody ever is curious about this, I tested out in full Sandbox and got this error when trying to insert a lead:

Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger leadFilter caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: leadFilter: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 100000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times):